# Django 4.2: Pagination doesn't work for me

Tags: django, pagination

I'm trying to use **pagination** in **Django**.
Here is my code:

- Views.py

  ```
  from catalog.models import Book
  from django.views import generic 

  class BookListView(generic.ListView):
      """Display authors per 10"""
      model = Book
      paginate_by = 10
  ```
- author_list.html

  ```
  {% extends "catalog/base.html" %}
  {% load static %}
  {% block content %}
  <h1> Authors </h1>
  {% if perms.catalog.can_add_author %}<p> <a href="{% url "author-create" %}"> New author </a></p>{% endif %}
  <figure>
      <img src="{% static "catalog/images/author.png" %}" alt="library" width=300/>
  </figure>
  {% if author_list %}
  <ul>
      {% for author in author_list  %}
          <li> <a href="{{author.get_absolute_url}}"> {{author}} </a> </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
  <p>  No author. </p>
  {% endif %}
  {% endblock content %}
  ```
- base.html

  ```
  {% load static %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "catalog/css/style.css" %}"/>
          {% block title %}<title> Local Library </title>{% endblock title %}
      </head>
      <body>
          {% block sidebar %}
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <p> <u> Hello {{user.get_username}} </u> </p>
          {% endif %}
          <nav>
              <ul>
                  <li> <a href="{% url "index" %}"> Home </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="{% url "books" %}"> Books </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="{% url "authors" %}"> Authors </a> </li>
                  {% if perms.catalog.can_see_borrowed_book %}
                  <li> <a href="{% url "borrowed-book" %}"> Books borrowed </a> </li>
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                  <li> <a href="{% url "my-borrowed" %}"> My books </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="{% url "logout" %}?next={{request.path}}"> Log out </a> </li>
                  {% else %}
                  <li> <a href="{% url "login" %}?next={{request.path}}"> Log in </a> </li>
                  {% endif %}

              </ul>
          </nav>
          {% endblock sidebar %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
          {% block pagination %}
              {% if is_paginated %}
                  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                      <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
                      <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                  {% endif %}

                  <span>
                      Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                  </span>

                  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                      <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                      <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
                  {% endif %}
              {% endif %}

          {% endblock pagination %}
      </body>
      </html>
  ```

Not only,  it doesn't show  authors per 10 (all authors are displayed) but also don't show  pagination even thought i have 15 authors.
How to make sure that *is_paginated* is correctly passed in the context.
Can someone help me please !

Comment: You show a list ofr books, but the template is about `Author`s?

Comment: You're right ! I juste noticed that i copied the code from  the view which displays a list of books instead of authors.
But in the code, the view that displays a list of authors has the model: Author.

Answer (score 1):

You should enumerate over the `page_obj`:

```
{% if page_obj %}
<ul>
    {% for author in page_obj %}
        <li> <a href="{{author.get_absolute_url}}"> {{author}} </a> </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>  No author. </p>
{% endif %}
```